# COM executable; how to create the Proxy / Stub DLL

Tags: com, arm, atl, windows-embedded-compact

I am developing a COM object for Windows Embedded Compact 7 on an iMX28 Armv5 board.

I have built the OSDesign through Platform Builder and generated the SDK. When creating the ATL Smart Device COM project against my SDK, when I select to create it as an executable it doesn't create the Proxy / Stub DLL that is usually created if I were building it as a Win32 executable.

I have tried manually copying / editing an xxxPS.DLL project to the solution and adding the i.c, i_p.c, .def and dlldata.c as explained in [Building Proxy/Stub dll in VS 2008](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1047656/building-proxy-stub-dll-in-vs-2008) but all without success.

Any ideas how I can get my COM EXE to generate the Proxy / stub dll?

Comment: Does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12986618/out-of-process-com-server-without-a-proxy-stub-dll I ask because perhaps "oleautomation" is missing, or a type was specified that COM doesn't know?